# Simple way to hook C/C++ functions in iphone?

Tags: ios, hook, jailbreak, cydia

Is there a simple hook function that can assist me in hooking C/C++ functions inside a dylib?

I know how to use the MSHookMessage functions, but i don't have a simple source for MSHookFunction.

I have tried to work on the sources from saurik - but it is hell to try compiling it...

Any good example out there? (not usage examples, implementation example).

EDIT:
I have tried to read about THEOS - but also didn't understand how to hook C functions...
it says here that teh directives only work for Classes:

%hook Classname

is it possible to hook functions this way?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with [CFBundleGetFunctionPointerForName](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFOundation/Reference/CFBundleRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFBundleGetFunctionPointerForName).

See [Loading Non-Cocoa Bundles](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingCode/Tasks/LoadingBundles.html), Listings 2 and 3. Works great even for private frameworks. You just have to know the location of the framework on disk.

Comment: After re-reading your question, I see you're asking specifically about dylibs, not frameworks. I've never tried exactly that, but you might check the man page for dlopen, etc.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to hook for Instanse the springboard. App. C functions.., will your suggestion work?

Comment: My mistake. Yeah if you need to replace the implementation of a C function in springboard, you'll need MSHookMessage. This will probably require a kernel patch to get the supercall closures to work, so you'll probably want to work through the getting started guide. Sorry for the red herring.

Comment: can you post a link to this guide?